# Accessing request from external url

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco7

Hi I'm new to umbraco MVC.  I'm using version 7.  What I'm trying to do is following:

An External page www.ble1.com is posting to my page www.le2.com/recieve when that happens ble1 is posting to the page and in the browser dev tools I can see the Form Data name of the parameter (tok) and some encoded string.

Now I want to take this data and send it to the controller code behind the macro running on my page www.le2.com/recieve.  How would this be possible?  I'm used to workin in asp.NET where I have the pageLoad function in code behind but I'm confused how to tackle this in Umbraco MVC.

What I have done so far is Create cshtml:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '../../../umbraco/surface/land/Login',
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        }
    });

});
</script>


My Controller 

public JsonResult Login()
{
//Don't know what to do here!!!!  
//Everything that I have tryed has failed.  Calling Request....etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked with Umbraco, but I have with MVC.

1. You `Login` method is not marked to receive POST requests. You need to use the attribute `[HttpPost]`
2. Your `Login` method does not have any Arguments, so, even if you fix your issue #1, it will not get any data.

So, first, you need some data in your Action Method, so you either need a ViewModel or a set or parameters, this is a ViewModel sample:

```
public class MyLoginViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Now we use that ViewModel in the Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login(MyLoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do something here (probably use Umbraco internal's authorization layer)
        var valid = (model.UserName == "user" && model.Password == "pwd");

        if (valid)
            return Json(new { code = 0, message = "OK" });
        else
            return Json(new { code = 10, message = "User/Password does not match" });
    }
    // Model is invalid, report error
    return Json(new { code = -1, message = "invalid arguments" });
}
```

It is a very naive example, it makes sure the ViewModel is Valid, if it is, it performs the actual login logic, in this sample is just checks 2 values and returns the status.

In the HTML page, you could have:

```
<input type="text" id="userName" />
<input type="text" id="password" />
<button id="login">Login</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '/home/Login',
                data: JSON.stringify({ UserName: $('#userName').val(), Password: $('#password').val() }),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.message);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("An error has occurred while processing your request");
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Again, very a naive example.

I hope it gives you enough information to adapt it to Umbraco.

Sorry I cannot give you Umbraco specific information.

Comment: Hi Daniel thanks for your answer.  I't points me to the right direction but my problem is **how to get** and send the Form Data info into the MyLoginViewModel as a parameter. Do I do that in some JQuery and then how?

Comment: I just updated my response with more details, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks again Daniel.  But my problem is that I need to get the Form Data from the external page that is posting to my page.  My page is being called from an External url that posts to my page and is posting a data that I need to let jQuer read and send down to the controller. I have no problem sending some user input to he controller the problem is how to send the Form Data from the external post down to then controller.

Comment: I thought the jQuery sample you showed was the code in the "external url", and that was to code that was posting the data to your controller. If you do not have control over the external page and that is already "posting" data to you, Why would you need jQuery?, just change your controller method to `public ActionResult Index(string tok) {//other logic here}` and you will be able to read the data from `tok`. (`tok` is the data been posted by the external page, right?)